# Unable to write Mat into JPG or any other image format other than BMP for OpenCV/C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm unable to use the function imwrite to write a Mat into a image file. It works fine when I am trying to write it into a BMP format , but it gives me an unhandled exception when trying to write into other formats.

```
        merge(yuv_channels,3,resImg);
        imshow("Result",resImg);
        imwrite("C:\\result.jpg",resImg);
```

The above code is my attempt for saving into jpg .

```
        merge(yuv_channels,3,resImg);
        imshow("Result",resImg);
        imwrite("C:\\result.bmp",resImg);
```

It works fine when I changed the extension to bmp though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated . 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you have write permission to [C:\\]. By default you haven't, in Windows Vista and later. Yes it sucks.

Comment: Yup I have write permission to [C:\]. Like I've said earlier i was able to successfully write it into bmp but not other image formats .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of resImg might be of incorrect format. Only 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF. If the format, depth or channel order is different, use Mat::convertTo() , and cvtColor() to convert it before saving. See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite

Comment: Ok thanks . Would you happen to have a sample code on how to use convertTo() ? or rather what should I use for the rtype argument ? 

C++: void Mat::convertTo(OutputArray m, int rtype, double alpha=1, double beta=0 )

Comment: I've never used converTo myself. Sorry